# Run func() when press a cell, except for the image that is found in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td column="Name" class="DesignedTableTD DesignedTableMainTD">
    adsasdasd
    <img class="editPencil" src="../../Images/edit_pencil_icon.png" 
    onclick="updateAccountName(this.parentNode);" style="opacity: 0.8;">
</td>
```

Is there a way to do the next thing:

when the user presses the td, run a function: `func()`, but when he presses the `img`, run the func: `updateAccountName`.

maybe somthing like:

```
$('td[column="name" and children!=img]').click(function() { func(); });
```

`children!=img` is a pseudo code..

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to use `e.target`(jQuery event field)([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/7hqg2/)):

```
$('td[column="Name"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var nodeName = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (nodeName === 'td') {
        func();
    } else if (nodeName === 'img') {
        updateAccountName();
    }
});
```

Also note that `HTML attribute` values are case **sensitive**. Remember this then using `td[column="name"]` for `td[column="Name"]`